# How to detach Cypress test runner from a page?

Tags: authentication, puppeteer, cypress, auth0

I'm trying to use Cypress with a site that redirects users to a third-party site for authentication. Once a user logs in, they're automatically redirected back to the site we control. From what I've read, Cypress doesn't support this particular set up.

Authentication at the third-party site can happen through a popup as well. And I can make Cypress open that popup.

Is there a way I can detach the Cypress test runner from the log-in popup so that it's no longer under control by Cypress? If so, how is this done? I would like to do this so that I can automate the log-in with something else (namely, Puppeteer) and then run the actual tests in the base page in the Cypress iframe.

[image]

Comment: you should just intercept the request and return the response that is expected so you stay on your website only

Comment: @mosaad, unfortunately, that doesn't work out in this situation. This Auth0 SSO absolutely requires authenticating off their own site (not remotely through API endpoints or anything like that). Using the popup for authentication would at least keep the base page on our application. In other words, all the redirecting to a third-party site would happen on the popup. So automating that would work if I could make Cypress yield control.

Comment: Can't you change how it works in tests environment?

Comment: I do not wish to introduce any type of security vulnerability just for the sake of Cypress. We have a test user account for non-prod environments that will work in this scenario if I can simply automate the log-in. Currently, I'm considering tossing Cypress and going with a Jest-Puppeteer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can assume the AUT is accepting a request from the 3rd party at some point in time, there should be a solution where you fire that api request with `cy.request` in the same manner as the UI.

You'll likely have to store environment variables, or some other auth security for the key, but if you do that, the login flow can be replicated by Cypress without having to use their 3rd party code; which you won't be able to access with Cypress if it's an iframe or other common 3rd party auth UI setup.